# Container's clipped children not visible on scrolling

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a VBox inside a Canvas. The 'red bars' are custom components based on 'Canvas'. All red bars are of equal height. I have 20 red bars inside the VBox. The scrollbars visible in the screenshot are the Canvas's scrollbars. The scrollbars of the VBox are disabled using `verticalScrollPolicy = off`.

Without scrolling, only 16 red bars (and a part of the 17th bar) are visible. However, when I scroll down the Canvas I expect to see the remaining red bars - but the bars that are not visible when the application starts don't get 'drawn'. What am I doing wrong? I want the user to be able to see the 17th - 20th bars when the Canvas is scrolled down.

**INITIAL VIEW**
[Before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfrWr.png)

**AFTER SCROLLING DOWN**
[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNoiE.png)

Also note, that after scrolling, the last red bar isn't completely drawn either.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. My bad. The VBox's height was explicitly set to the height of the Canvas. So this behaviour was expected. And since the VBox's scrollbars were disabled, its content (which was actually drawn, but not visible) could not be seen.